# Как заставить bot.send_message отправлять сообщение всем user_id из массива

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда боту писали сообщение с определенным идентификатором, бот записывал бы user_id отправителя в массив, и потом, после того, как я введу определенную команду, бот отправлял бы одно и тоже сообщение всем user_id из данного массива.

Например так user_id попадает в массив

```
myarray = [] * 10
c2 = "с2"

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if c2 in message.text.lower():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично, твое сообщение получено")
        myarray.append(message.from_user.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['sendtoarray'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(myarray, "Сообщение")
```

Если в последней строчке вписать вместо "myarray" user_id того, кто уже писал боту какие-либо сообщения, то код работает. Но если заставить его взять все user_id из массива (например массив был бы таким: [user_id, user_id]) то ничего не работает.

Это вообще возможно как-то сделать? В идеале мне нужно 4 идентификатора и 4 массива соответственно.

Comment: Генераторы в помощь.

Comment: Чем не устраивает обход списка в цикле? И зачем нужна эта странная конструкция - `[] * 10`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так и сделал, вроде работает, спасибо.